# exporting registry keys to .reg file in windows OS using perl 5

Tags: windows, key, registry, export

I want the below function to be implemented in perl script:

How to export a registry key,along with all its sub keys, into a dot reg file using Perl script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reg.exe to do this.
[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742017.aspx) is a link to the technet description of the command but it is basically just

```
Reg export KeyName FileName
```

Comment: I tried this from perl script. I used the command like                                `reg export $SourceKey "$TargerDIR\\Test.reg"`.   But the script is returning with the below error:                                                                                                 sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `reg export Win32::TieRegistry=HASH(0x1097d4c8) "C:\targetdir\
test.reg"'

Comment: it is a call to an external windows program not perl syntax, sorry if that was not clear. I don't know perl but from what I found with a quick search you would probably call it with "system()" or "exec()"